# Difference between these two algorithms

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

Problem is to return removed duplicated numbers in array. [link](https://leetcode.com/explore/interview/card/top-interview-questions-easy/92/array/727)

This is solution.

```
    dict1={}
    arr=[]
    for i in nums:
        if i not in dict1:
            dict1[i]=1
            arr.append(i)
    nums[:]=arr
    return len(nums)
```

This is my approach... Why is it not working?

```
    hash = {}
    for num in nums:
        if num in hash:
            nums.remove(num)
        hash[num] = num
    return len(nums)
```

I've been working on this problem more than 30 minutes :(

Comment: is it a function?

Comment: or 2 functions?

Comment: Just added return statement. And yes, these are two separate functions. Thanks!

Comment: How does for-loop work in Python when you remove elements on the fly?

Comment: @MBo - in general it screws things up in one or more ways.

Comment: It works on my laptop but it doesnt work on leetcode terminal. Weird

Comment: You are changing your `nums` as you iterate through it. It seems that this could be done using comprehension. Could you add example of input and desired output?

Comment: Please post what you mean by "not working", a [mcve] would be most welcome. Also, have you tried to debug your code to see what is actually happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an algorithm point of view, the second one does not look good as the `remove` have a higher time complexity than the hash insertion and deletion. Therefore, the removal time is more than `O(1)`. The first implementation uses an additional list. Also, instead of maintaining another array you can also do `list (hash.keys ())` and return it.

Python list removal is `O(n)` for both average and amortized case (check https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity?), but dict operation is `O(1)` in average case and `O(n)` amortized time. In this case I marking the elements in a dict and then returning the keys is a better idea.

Although, in this case I think using a set `set` to mark the unique items may be a better idea, as it will not only be faster, but also lighter on memory.

From the code point of view, do not modify a list which you are iterating through, unless you access and modify the list using index and take care of the list modification and index manipulation yourself.

Comment: Need to study based on your answer. Thank you so much and I feel like I need to learn more from you.